# How can I extract the numbers from this string?

Tags: r, regex, string

The question I'm asking is in `string1`:

```
string1 <- "We have to extract these numbers 12, 47, 48 The integers numbers are also interesting: 189 2036 314 \',\' is a separator, so please extract these numbers 125,789,1450 and also these 564,90456 We like to offer you 7890$ per month in order to complete this task... we are joking"


str_match_all(string1,"[0-9]{2}")
```

output looks like this

```
[[1]]
      [,1]
 [1,] "12"
 [2,] "47"
 [3,] "48"
 [4,] "18"
 [5,] "20"
 [6,] "36"
 [7,] "31"
 [8,] "12"
 [9,] "78"
[10,] "14"
[11,] "50"
[12,] "56"
[13,] "90"
[14,] "45"
[15,] "78"
[16,] "90"
```

but I need it to look like this

```
 [1,] "12"   
 [2,] "47"   
...
[12,] "7890"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want:

```
library(magrittr)
gsub("\\D", "", strsplit(string1, split="[ ,\\$]")[[1]]) %>% { .[. != ""] }
```

Package `magrittr` is what gives you the pipe operator `%>%` that allows you to do this all on one line.

Generally, I find it best to chip away at the unwanted parts of a string rather than to try to identify the parts that I want by way of a regular expression. In this case, the string in your example first gets split into 57 pieces by the `strsplit` function, based on three separators. Some of those pieces are numeric, and others aren't. The `gsub` turns all the non-numeric ones into blank strings (""). This is piped to the last step, where only the non-blank strings are extracted.

And voila!

```
> gsub("\\D", "", strsplit(string1, split="[ ,\\$]")[[1]]) %>% { .[. != ""] }
 [1] "12"    "47"    "48"    "189"   "2036"  "314"   "125"   "789"   "1450"
[10] "564"   "90456" "7890"
```